# How can I postpone test verification?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

So, the problem is next:
I have a class with tests.
EXP of this class:

```
class TestClass:

   def test1(self):

   step 1 (some method to create test data)
   ...
   ...
   step n (some method to create test data)

   
   expected = result of step 1 ... step n execution


   actual = method_a()--> get actual results from some resources (2 min is needed for this data to 
                 be created on this resource)
   
   verification_method(expected, actual) 



   def test2(self):

   step 1 (some method to create test data)
   ...
   ...
   step n (some method to create test data)

   
   expected = result of step 1 ... step n execution


   actual = method_a()--> get actual results from some resources (2 min is needed for this data to 
                 be created on this resource)
   
   verification_method(expected, actual)
```

So, in that case, execution will take at least 2 min * number of tests.
How can I move `actual = method_a()--> get actual results from some resources (2 min is needed for this data to be created on this resource)` and as a result `verification_method(expected, actual)` to "something " what will be executed after all tests.

For now, I have a global variable `test_name_and_expected_result` which contains `expected` for all tests, and move

```
actual = method_a()--> get actual results from some resources (2 min is needed for this data to 
                     be created on this resource)
       
       verification_method(expected, actual)
```

to **class fixture teardown**. But as a result, I have no proper test status as I can see only general failure but not for a specific test.

**Also works for me :**
If there is the possibility to forcibly overwrite pytest results for a specific test (as I have the name of tests in `test_name_and_expected_result`)

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, but that can be an issue of terminology. Are your tests not testing `method_a`? If we can agree on that, you're actually trying to move the preparation steps to *before* the test, not the other way around.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, method_a - is a function which returns data from Amazon S3 after all steps where executed

Comment: So, test body contains a lot of different steps (and custom validation for each tests), but what is same in all tests -   'actual = method_a()'-get data from S3 and 'verification_method(expected, actual)'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.